# Why the t.test does not work inside this function in R?

Tags: r

I am creating a function for conducting t.test on various columns of a data frame. Following is an example with the Orange data set in R:

```
> t.test(Orange[Orange$Tree=="1",]$age, 
+        Orange[Orange$Tree=="2",]$age)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Orange[Orange$Tree == "1", ]$age and Orange[Orange$Tree == "2", ]$age
t = 0, df = 12, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -609.832  609.832
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 922.1429  922.1429
```

But when this is done inside the following function it doesn't work:

```
my.t.test <- function(var, df){
  df <- na.omit(df)
  tt1 <- t.test(df[df$Tree=="1",]$var, 
                df[df$Tree=="2",]$var)
  tt1
}

> my.t.test(age, Orange)
Error in var(x) : 'x' is NULL
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
Called from: var(x)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the functions `[` or `[[` to subset with a variable name, ie.

```
my.t.test <- function(var, df){
  df <- na.omit(df)
  tt1 <- t.test(df[df$Tree=="1",var], 
                df[df$Tree=="2",var])
  tt1
}

my.t.test("age", Orange)
```

You can read about this [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html), scroll down to the section on `$`.  The problem in your code is just that it is trying to subset `Orange` like `Orange[["var"]]`, and `var` doesn't exist.

Because of partial matching with `$`, if you added a column named "variable" to `Orange`, `$var` will match that column (but notice it doesn't matter what argument you pass to the function for `var`)

```
## Add column
Orange$variable <- "testing123"

## Test function
tst <- function(var, df) df$var

tst("somethingElse", Orange)
# [1] "testing123" "testing123" "testing123" "testing123" "testing123" ...
```